# Django JOIN. select data + select count

Tags: python, django, join

Two models:

```
class KeywordCategory(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'keywords_category'
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
...
class Keyword(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = 'keywords'
    keyword_category = models.ForeignKey(KeywordCategory)
    keyword_text     = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I need to get all the categories and the count of entries in them.

SQL syntax:

```
SELECT keywords_category.*, COUNT(keywords.id) as count_keywords
FROM keywords_category
LEFT JOIN keywords ON keywords_category.id=keywords.keyword_category_id
GROUP by keywords_category.id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will return a dictionary and the keys will be `keyword_category` and `total`.

```
from django.db.models import Count

kw_counts = Keyword.objects.all().values('keyword_category').annotate(
    total=Count('keyword_category')
)
```

Comment: @qor1x `.objects.values('keyword_category__category_name')`

Answer (score 0):

Get all the categories:

```
categories = KeywordCategory.objects.all()
```

Count the entries in them:

```
for category in categories:
    category.keyword_set.count()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
keywords = KeywordCategory.objects.all()

print [(k, k.keyword_set.count()) for k in keywords]
```